# How to use LookRotation to rotate an object based on hand positions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry, quaternions

I'm creating an interaction system for a VR game and I'm struggling with two hand interactions. I'm using the [`Quaternion.LookRotation()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) method to generate the rotation of the grabbed object based on the positions and rotations of the hands. The forward part is pretty simple:

```
Vector3 fwd = (primaryHand.position - secondaryHand.position).normalized;
```

The "up" part is what I have difficulty with. Initially I tried using the average up direction of both hands:

```
Vector3 avgUp = Quaternion.Slerp(primaryHand.rotation, secondaryHand.rotation, 0.5f) * Vector3.up;
```

There is an issue with this approach: the hand's up vector might get aligned with the `fwd` vector, which causes the object to flip over when it goes over it. Here is a simple illustration of the problem:
[image: Small direction changes can cause the object to flip over.]
The light green arrows represent the up direction of the hands, while the dark green is the calculated direction used as an argument for the `LookRotation()` method.

The obvious solution seems to be to pick a different fixed vector instead of "up", one which won't be so easily aligned with the `fwd` vector. In the example it could be a vector aligned with the fingers. But keep in mind that there are no restrictions on initial hand rotation so no matter which vector you choose the hands can always happen to be rotated so that the vectors align. And even if you pick the an optimal vector dynamically (one that is perpendicular to `fwd`), it's still at best 90 degrees from aligning with `fwd`.

To solve this I tried restricting the direction to the values which don't cause problems but this caused another issues (I had difficulties with determining which values are ok and which should be discarded). I feel like I'm doing something wrong here, is there any better solution to this problem?

Comment: question is unclear. What is the desired average up in the lower diagram? What is the desired average up in event is left hand in upper diagram and right hand in lower diagram?

Comment: What is the desired average up in the event hands do [this](https://i.imgur.com/goA3hq4.png) or if the hands are vertically offset like [this](https://i.imgur.com/I1Af4mT.png)

Comment: Lastly what is the expected up if the arms are crossed like [this](https://i.imgur.com/vOHLamd.png)?

Comment: @Ruzihm the image I provided was just to illustrate the issue, not exactly to act as a reference. The game is 3D while the images are 2D so I can't exactly convey everything using them. In case of the first situation you provided, it depends on how exactly the hands are rotated. If the rotation axis was parallel to the `fwd` vector then the `avgUp` should be pointed down. However if the rotation axis was perpendicular to the `fwd` vector then I would like the `avgUp` to be up. To generalize: I want to keep only the rotations which happen around the `fwd` vector while discarding the others.

Comment: In regards to the second image I can't really tell since it's a 2D projection and I don't want to cause confusion. I know this is quite complex so please let me know if something from my previous comment is unclear.

Comment: what's the local direction of a vector going into the back of the hands and emerging out of the palms? forward? The diagram shows that a vector going from the thumb side of the hand to the pinky side is local up, for instance.

Comment: It's actually down (-up), I just drew it like this since it was a 2D image. Forward is aligned with the fingers and right is on the opposite side of the thumb for the right hand.

Comment: One thing that might be helpful to you regarding the two situations I described in my first comment - you can differentiate between them based on the directions of other vectors like forward or right. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the hand axes: https://imgur.com/a/GBg9arj.

Comment: So that is to say, local right is the side with thumb for the left hand, not local down like it is labeled in the diagram?

Comment: Yes, right is on the thumb side for the left hand. To avoid confusion here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/EgNaetu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the delta rotations of the hands and apply it to the "base up" of the object (the new up if we only take into account the change in position of hands...which will of course be orthogonal to the axis of the object). Then determine the change in angle that results in that up being rotated with each hand. Average those angles out, then apply those angles with the hand-hand axis using Quaternion.AngleAxis to the "base up" from earlier. Then you have your forward and up for Quaternion.LookRotation).

Below is an example of how you can use this, including VR hand noise simulation. To see the test, create a new scene in unity and attach this to the camera and it will build the scene on play start. There is a grip/release gui that will appear in Play view. You can adjust the hand rotation in Scene view

[image: example of use]

```
    Vector3 leftHandPosCurrent;
    Vector3 rightHandPosCurrent;

    Vector3 worldAxisPrev;

    Quaternion leftHandRotPrev;
    Quaternion leftHandRotCurrent;

    Quaternion rightHandRotPrev;
    Quaternion rightHandRotCurrent;

    bool isGripping;
    bool firstFrameGripping;

    Rigidbody grippedRB;

    Transform leftHand;
    Transform rightHand;

    Quaternion targetRot;

    /* 
     * On subsequent frames of gripping, calculate deltas in positions and
     * rotations, average out the hand's effects, then apply them to the gripped
     * object
     */
    void HandleGrippedRot()
    {
        Vector3 worldAxisCurrent = rightHandPosCurrent - leftHandPosCurrent;

        if (!firstFrameGripping)
        {
            Vector3 prevUp = targetRot * Vector3.up;
            // we haven't moved the transform based on the hands yet, so 
            // find the new up would be ignoring hand rotations
            Vector3 newUp = Quaternion.FromToRotation(worldAxisPrev,
                    worldAxisCurrent) * prevUp;

            float leftHandAngle = GetDegRot(newUp, leftHandRotPrev,
                    leftHandRotCurrent, worldAxisCurrent);
            float rightHandAngle = GetDegRot(newUp, rightHandRotPrev,
                    rightHandRotCurrent, worldAxisCurrent);
            float avgAngle = (leftHandAngle + rightHandAngle) * 0.5f;

            newUp = Quaternion.AngleAxis(avgAngle, worldAxisCurrent) * prevUp;

            targetRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(worldAxisCurrent,
                    newUp);
        }
        else
        {
            firstFrameGripping = false;
        }

        leftHandRotPrev = leftHandRotCurrent;
        rightHandRotPrev = rightHandRotCurrent;

        worldAxisPrev = worldAxisCurrent;
    }

    /*
     * Given the "up" of the object without taking hand rotations into account
     * and the axis, determine how a hand's delta rotation affects that up 
     * around the axis and return the angle of that rotation 
     */
    float GetDegRot(Vector3 baseUp, Quaternion prevHandRot, Quaternion curHandRot,
            Vector3 axis)
    {
        Vector3 adjUp = (curHandRot * Quaternion.Inverse(prevHandRot)) * baseUp;
        adjUp = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(adjUp, axis);

        return Vector3.SignedAngle(baseUp, adjUp, axis);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        AddVRNoise(leftHand);
        AddVRNoise(rightHand);

        leftHandPosCurrent = leftHand.position;
        rightHandPosCurrent = rightHand.position;

        leftHandRotCurrent = leftHand.rotation;
        rightHandRotCurrent = rightHand.rotation;


        if (isGripping)
        {
            HandleGrippedRot();
        }
    }

    void StartGrip()
    {
        if (isGripping) return;
        isGripping = true;
        firstFrameGripping = true;
        // grippedTransform is set accordingly at some point
    }

    void EndGrip()
    {
        if (!isGripping) return;
        isGripping = false;
    }

    /*
     * example of using targetRot to move rb
     */
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!isGripping) return;

        Quaternion delta = targetRot
                * Quaternion.Inverse(grippedRB.transform.rotation);

        delta.ToAngleAxis(out float angle, out Vector3 axis);

        // convert to shortest angle form
        if (angle > 180f)
        {
            axis = -axis; angle = 360f - angle;
        }

        grippedRB.angularVelocity = angle * 0.25f * axis;
    }

    /*
     * just for testing purposes
     */
    void Start()
    {
        leftHand = CreateHand(true);
        leftHand.position = Vector3.left;

        rightHand = CreateHand(false);
        rightHand.position = Vector3.right;

        CreateArrow();
    }

    /*
     * just for testing purposes
     */
    void AddVRNoise(Transform hand)
    {
        Quaternion noise = Random.rotation;
        noise.ToAngleAxis(out float angle, out Vector3 axis);
        angle = 100f * Time.deltaTime;
        noise = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);

        Quaternion noisyRot = hand.rotation * noise;
        hand.rotation = noisyRot;
    }

    /*
     * just for testing purposes
     */
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 50), "Grip"))
        {
            StartGrip();
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 0, 100, 50), "Release"))
        {
            EndGrip();
        }
    }


    /*
     * just for testing purposes
     */
    Transform CreateHand(bool isLeft)
    {
        string handName = isLeft ? "Left" : "Right";
        GameObject hand = new GameObject($"{handName}hand");
        GameObject palm = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        palm.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.2f, 1f);
        palm.transform.SetParent(hand.transform);
        GameObject thumb = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        thumb.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.2f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
        thumb.transform.SetParent(hand.transform);
        thumb.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(isLeft ? 0.32f : -0.32f,
                0f, -.31f);

        return hand.transform;
    }

    /*
     * just for testing purposes
     */
    void CreateArrow()
    {
        GameObject arrow = new GameObject();
        GameObject body = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        body.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 5f);
        body.transform.SetParent(arrow.transform);
        GameObject head = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        head.transform.SetParent(arrow.transform);
        head.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.up * 45f;
        head.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 2.5f);

        grippedRB = arrow.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        grippedRB.useGravity = false;

        arrow.transform.position = 2f * Vector3.up;
    }
```

Comment: I will test it out as soon as possible. Do you think there is a way to make this stateless (without remembering the previous rotation)? Saving the previous state is fine but can lead to some issues in my experience.

Comment: @WojtekWencel It has to be stateful because the current position & orientation of the hands isn't enough information. Consider the following involving two cases. Begin both cases with the right hand palm down fingers forward, left hand is to the left, near the thumb of the right hand. Case 1: Rotate right hand 90 degrees along finger axis in the direction causing thumb to point up, then rotating right hand 90 degrees along palm axis causing fingers to point up. Object should have rotated to point its up slightly towards the player.

Comment: Case 2: Rotate right hand 90 degrees along finger axis in the other direction causing thumb to point down, then rotating right hand around palm axis 270 degrees causing fingers to point up, then finally rotating right hand around finger axis 180 degrees causing thumb to point toward self. Object should have rotated to point its up away from the player, even though hands are in final situation of case 1.

Comment: I see what you mean with these examples, but I tested the code and it seems to be very unstable, which I think is due to numerical errors accumulating every frame. I think a stateless solution would be better because of this, even at a cost of some non-linear rotation changes in certain cases (as long as they don't happen as easy as the one described in the question). But please test this and let me know because maybe it's caused by something else than what I'm suspecting.

Comment: I renamed variables a few times in the course of writing the answer, it was supposed to be `baseUp`. The other line should be something like `newUp = Quaternion.AngleAxis(avgAngle, worldAxisCurrent) * prevUp;`. I made these edits now in the answer if you'd like to see. Still can't currently test, but will be able to later

Comment: Works great, even better than I thought it could, thanks! For anyone implementing this, `targetRot` has to be reset to `Quaternion.identity` when starting a new interaction.